# How can we merge two video in which one is horizontal resolution and other one is vertical resolution without stretching it using ffmpeg?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to make an application that merge two video, in which one video is of vertical resolution and other one is of horizontal resolution. I managed to merge but it leads to stretching of video which ideally shouldn't happen. Does anyone have any idea to do this? Thank you!

```
command = new String[]{"-y", "-i", video1.mp4, "-i", video2.mp4,"-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex",
            "[0:v]scale=1920x1080,setdar=4:3[v0];[1:v]scale=1920x1080,setdar=4:3[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1",
            "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "1920x1080", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-crf", "27", "-q", "4", "-preset", "ultrafast",output.mp4};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to scale proportionally and then pad.

```
[0:v]scale=1920x1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:'(ow-iw)/2':'(oh-ih)/2'[v0];
[1:v]scale=1920x1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:'(ow-iw)/2':'(oh-ih)/2'[v1];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i tried and still its not working. Can you please send me whole command?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setsar=1` after giving padding.

eg.

```
[0:v]scale=1920x1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:'(ow-iw)/2':'(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1'[v0];
```